# Сортировка строк по алфавиту по концовке

Tags: c#

Столкнулся я с такой проблемой:
Есть текстовой документ, в нем для примера 8 строк:

```
test4:ac
test6:at
test2:ab
test8:aq
test7:au
test1:ah
test3:ap
test5:as
```

Что-то похожее здесь написано но немного не то что надо было бы иметь в результате
https://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-beginners/thread2225545.html

Как получить такой вывод, но уже в другом `result.txt`

```
test2:ab
test4:ac
test1:ah
test3:ap
test8:aq
test5:as
test6:at
test7:au
```

Но в коде нужно прописать типа **Substring посл. 2 символа с конца**

Comment: `string.Join(' ', lines.OrderBy(x => x.Split(':')[1]))`

Answer (score 2):

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("path/name1.txt"); // считать строки из файла
var sortedLines = lines.OrderBy(x => x.Split(':').Last()); // просортировать по концовке
File.WriteAllText("path/name2.txt", sortedLines); // записать в новый файл
```

---

Если строго следовать постановке задачи: "последние 2 символа с конца", то решение может быть таким:

```
lines.OrderBy(x => x[^2..])
```

Тут используются [Индексы и диапазоны](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/ranges-indexes):

`^2..` - означает диапазон от двух символов с конца и до конца.

Comment: А общий то зачем?

Comment: @aepot я по-сути просто переписал комментарий EvgeniyZ